# Non-linear Galois descent

Tags: galois-theory, topos-theory, monoidal-categories, galois-descent

This question is about Galois theory. So let $K / k$ be a Galois extension of fields. Let us assume that $K / k$ is finite dimensional, though everything can be made to work in the profinite case by adding some continuity conditions here and there. I should perhaps remark that I do not (yet) know Grothendieck's Galois theory. If this theory answers my question, I will be happy with some precise statement.
$\newcommand{\Mod}{\mathrm{Mod}}\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}$

Let $\Mod(K/k)$ be the category of *$K/k$-vector spaces*: Objects are $K$-vector spaces $V$ together with an action of the Galois group $\Gal(K/k)$ on $V$ which is semilinear in the sense that $\sigma(a v) = \sigma(a) \sigma(v)$ for $\sigma \in \Gal(K/k)$, $a \in K$ and $v \in V$. Morphisms are $K$-linear maps which commute with the action.

Now Galois descent is the statement that the functors
$$\Mod(k) \to \Mod(K/k), \qquad V \mapsto K \otimes_k V$$
and
$$\Mod(K/k) \to \Mod(k), \qquad W \mapsto W^{\Gal(K/k)}$$
form an equivalence of ($k$-linear, symmetric monoidal, …) categories.

This induces equivalences of the respective categories of monoids (i.e. $k$-algebras on the left hand side), which is related to Brauer groups, or of “objects with a bilinear form” (i.e. objects $V$ equipped with a map from $V \otimes V$ to the monoidal unit, satisfying some axioms), which is related to the Galois cohomology of the orthogonal group.

> Is there some equivalence between categories of non-linear objects, which induces the above equivalence between $k$-vector spaces and $K/k$-vector spaces? For example, is there some ringed topos $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ such that $\Mod(K/k)$ is more or less by definition the category of modules in this ringed topos and such that $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is equivalent to $(\mathrm{Set},k)$?

I have to admit that I do not really expect the answer to the above question to be “yes”. For example one way to prove Galois descent is to realise that $\Mod(K/k)$ is basically the category of modules over the twisted group algebra $K[\Gal(K/k)]$ and that by linear independence of characters, this algebra is isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}_k(K)$, which by Morita theory has the same module category as $k$. So one (though not commutative) ringed topos giving rise to $\Mod(K/k)$ would be $(\mathrm{Set},K[\Gal(K/k)])$, which is, of course, not equivalent to $(\mathrm{Set}, k)$. But maybe there is some category of sets with a “semi-linear“ Galois action (whatever that would mean) which could work? Or maybe there is a better suited topos than $(\mathrm{Set},k)$, which gives rise to $\Mod(k)$?

But in fact, every proof I can think of to prove Galois descent is based on the linear independence of characters and hence something very linear-ish. Another thing making me sceptical is that the functor $V \mapsto K \otimes_k V$ does not seem to have a non-linear equivalent. Therefore I would like to know:

> Is there any high-level explenation (more convincing than the one given in the above paragraph) why the answer to question 1 has to be “no”?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert but I would say this is absolutely not a linear-specific phenomenon. Schemes X (let's say of finite type but I'm not sure of the exact most general context here) over K plus a Gal equivariance (ie isoms X--->^{\sigma}X for all \sigma in Gal) are the same as schemes over k. Does this count as non-linear? I would say it does. For a pretty vast generalization look up faithfully flat descent.

Comment: @EBz Minor correction: you need algebraic spaces, not schemes for descent to work (or else to restrict yourself to, say, quasi-projective schemes).

Comment: I should say that schemes (or algebraic spaces) are not what I am after. I understand how one can argue that they are not linear objects, but in the hierarchy of mathematical objects they are based on affine schemes, which are algebras, which are based on vector spaces. I am looking for something that comes before vector spaces in the complexity hierarchy of mathematical objects – like sets.

Comment: @Denis Nardin, thanks, I was pretty confident I was missing some hypotheses!

Comment: Are you looking for sets ... with $k$-action?  Those are basically $k$-vector spaces.